# Split() function for two consecutive regex in end of String

Tags: java, regex

every one I want to use for the strings like

```
"Ravi;Dutt;;"
```

but when I use split 
    for this string . It gives result like mentioned above. I got an array of size 2.
    But in my requirement it should be of 3 as one for last two delimiters. Please help me 
    thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you use ; as delimeter? have you tried putting something between the last two ;'s? at this moment, there is no String there, so pretty normal it won't return anything

Comment: yes Stultuske. But basically my need is to split it in such a way that at first index of array it will be Ravi, Dutt on 2nd index and the third index must be empty only

Answer (score 2):

By default, trailing empty strings (those at the end of the array) are discarded.

If you want to include these as well, try

```
split(";", -1)
```

Comment: But you will end up with two empty Strings at the end.

Comment: my need is to split it in such a way that at first index of array it will be Ravi, Dutt on 2nd index and the third index must be empty only. But if I uses your idea it gives size four array it should be 3